# Unable to resize a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I'm using xcode 4.5 (incase that makes any difference) along with a Storyboard and I'm trying to do something seemingly very simple without any luck. In my storyboard view I have placed a UIView component as you can see in the image here http://www.shopow.co.uk/assets/storyboard-view.png where the green section is the UIView which has a height of 100

In the viewDidLoad method I've added the following code

```
NSLog(@"View Height: %f", self.testView.bounds.size.height);

CGRect viewFrame = self.testView.frame;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(viewFrame.size.width, 300);
viewFrame.size = newSize;
self.testView.frame = viewFrame;

NSLog(@"View Height: %f", self.testView.bounds.size.height);
```

From what I've read about resizing stuff I'd assume the green section to resize to be 300 high however this doesn't happen although the output in the log window shows the following

```
2012-10-19 13:05:28.015 TableTest[54318:c07] View Height: 460.000000
2012-10-19 13:05:28.016 TableTest[54318:c07] View Height: 300.000000
```

Notice the initial height being 460 rather than 100 which may mean something!

iOS simulator shows this http://www.shopow.co.uk/assets/simulator-view.png

I must be overlooking something obvious as far as I can tell this is not working as expected. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the testView linked right to the grean view? it seems like you linked it to controller's view

Comment: Hi, to add the UIView I just dragged it in and then linked it up as a property in the .h file like so `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;` and then synthesised it in the .m file. Should I be doing it a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but you should really do your view resizing in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`.

`viewDidLoad` literally means what it says, 'the view has loaded'. However, at this point your nib may not have set up the view as you would expect.

As a test, try logging the following in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

> NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));

You should see that in both methods you get different results. The `viewWillAppear` method is more likely to be correct as the view has been set up and is ready to be presented.

I personally don't use Interface Builder all that much as it causes more headaches than I can deal with but perhaps your auto-resizing masks or elastic constraints are set which is affecting the dimensions of your view?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the other comment I tried implementing it in the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods but had the same result. I'll look into the constraints to see if they're causing any issues although I've not adjusted them at all and I'd (maybe wrongly) assume that resizing would be possible with the default settings.

Comment: I think that by default auto-resizing is set to constrain all dimensions of a view. Check IB and remove all constraints if there are any. Other than that, something else may be aloof.

Comment: Even removing all contraints the subview does not resize. I created a new project with a single storyboard scene and tried it in that with the same code to rule out anything else and still the same thing happens. It also happen with Auto Layout on and off, in both cases with any constraints removed or otherwise. I'm well and truly stuck with this, I also can't find any samples anywhere where I can see it working so I might be able to compare what I'm doing.

Comment: It turned out to be AutoLayout in the end. Thanks for all you help.

Answer (score 0):

Like @CaptainRedmuff said, you're calling it in the wrong method. `viewDidLoad` is called after the view is loaded, which means the frame has already been set. The method you're looking for is `loadView`, as `viewWillAppear:animated` and `viewDidAppear:animated` are being called after `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hi, I switched it round so the code is now implemented in the `loadView` method but I'm still getting the same results. I also tried it in the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods with the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

OP wasn't really clear how he solved it. In case anyone else is having this problem.

If your view is showing the same layout as what you see in your storyboard despite the fact that you are programmatically resizing/changing its property in some way, this is because auto-layout is causing havoc.

Just select the view that you want to programmatically change and go to File Inspector in the Attributes pane. Deselect the checkbox next to Use Auto layout. Run again and you'll see your problem magically disappear.